# PFC circuit: Rectified AC voltage going beyond input AC voltage limits

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

We have a PFC circuit powered from a bridge rectifier as shown below:

Fig 1:
[image: Fig 1]

We have separate sense terminals to detect the AC voltage levels and accordingly enable the PFC converter (sample circuit shown below: Vacp enables PFC converter). PFC converter is there between full wave bridge rectifier and C1 (not shown in figure).

Fig 2:
[image]

Ideally the voltage at the output of the rectifier should be as shown in Fig 1, but what we see in the lab is Fig 3.

Can anyone explain why we see a difference in rectified AC sense voltage with and without PFC enabled? Not sure how the rectified AC can go well beyond the Vmax levels (~80 V).

Fig 3: (Vin RMS (AC) = 56 V)
[image]

Comment: 56V RMS is about 80V peak, is that the issue?

Comment: A thick trace means high frequencies are present. There is not much we can tell you about the waveform at this zoom level (which you helpfully cropped off the scales, so we don't know what these waveforms are). As for possible sources, I don't see anything represented in the equivalent circuit, but I think you know where high frequencies could be coming from.

Answer (score 0):

@bobflux is right, a bridge rectifier usually provides an output with peaks that are 1.41 times the RMS voltage.  The amount of ripple depends on the load.  The RMS voltage is the DC voltage that would provide the same average power to a resistive load as the AC signal.  Since it spends a portion of the time below the RMS voltage, it needs to spend some time above the RMS voltage to compensate.

The rectifier conducts during peak, charging the cap through the bypass diode.  In most such circumstances, the capacitor is large enough compared to the load that the peak voltage doesn't diminish much (ripple) during the off-peak moments.